# Repeating a Gherkin test

Tags: java, cucumber, repeat, gherkin

I can't believe that I am unable to find a specific answer to this; perhaps my own terrible searching skills today.  Anyway, I have a gherkin that I want to be able to just repeat 'x' number of times.  Is there a way to do this without having to rewrite the step definitions for tests to include looping code?  Maybe a line at the end of the gherkin that says something to the effect of 'repeat 10 times'?

Comment: this smells like bad test design. maybe explain your usecase a little bit more and then you can get useful tips on the initial design?

Answer (score 0):

My best recommendation would be to make a step that literally does nothing, such as:

`Given I have ran this test <number> times`

And make your Scenario a Scenario Outline, including examples spanning the amount of times you want to run your test.

The regex needed would look a little like:

`@Given("^I have ran this test (\\d+) times")`

The Scenario looking like this:

```
Feature: Run this 10 times

Scenario Outline: Lets do this
Given I have ran this test <number> times
...
Examples:
|number|
| 1    |
...
| 10   |
```

In my opinion, it would be the easiest way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Gherkin is not a programming language. It is not Turing complete. It doesn't have support for repetition, hence there is no possibility to do this in Gherkin.

I would introduce it in the step. Possible with a setting in gherkin of the number of repetitions.